# Frequent short freezes in games and videos

Tags: windows-7, freeze, gaming

I recently acquired an SSD drive and did a fresh install of Windows 7 on it.

Now, when playing games or watching videos, I get frequent (every 2-3 minutes) freezes which last a few seconds or less. They are accompanied by a buzzing sound.

While researching the issue, I've found many suggestions that this was due to the GPU overheating. According to Speedfan however, both my GPUs and CPU are running under 40°C.

The very curious thing is that when I boot my computer to the old Windows 7 on my other hard drive, the problem goes away. This leads me to believe that it's a software issue.

My AMD drivers are up to date, and I also updated DirectX just to be sure. Does anyone know what could be causing this ?

Info :
* OS : Windows 7
* CPU : AMD Phenom II x4 955
* RAM : 4096
* GPU : ATI Radeon 5770 x2, Crossfire

Note that the issue also occurs with just one GPU if I unplug the other one, so it's not due to Crossfire either.

Edit : Updated SSD Firmware, added 4GB of RAM. The issue still occurs, but less frequently. About every 5-15 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried to update the firmware for the SSD.  Its not clear what you believe is generating the buzzing sound.

Comment: Will try the SSD firmware update. Buzzing sound is in the audio, which comes from the motherboard.

Comment: Check your DPC latency with a program called DPCLAT

Comment: Hello @VoronoiPotato, I used DPCLAT as per your suggestion. Indeed, on occasions (about every 15 minutes or so), DPCLAT show latency going above 16000µs for an instant.

It does not seem to happen only while playing games or watching videos. It's just that it's much more noticeable when there is sound, because of the loop it makes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet you've got a hardware problem on your main hard drive or you have a driver conflict. Clone the drive to your old drive and you might see the problem disappear if that doesn't work try disabling different device drivers until the problem no longer persists.

Comment: So, If i do clone my current drive to the old drive and find out you are right, would that mean my SSD drive is damaged ? What is curious is that when I run games from my SSD while running Windows from my old HDD, they work fine. If it's a drive issue, would you have suggestions as to where to start ?

Comment: If it were a harddrive problem you as far as I know have the option of replacing the drive. You can try disabling drivers or chkdisk. try cloning the drive first though, and let us know if the problem persists